# Move to next element of array

Tags: java, for-loop

I need the below code to move to next line and not to restart from first line again

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
    String getTextArea;
    getTextArea = textArea.getText();
    String[] arr = getTextArea.split("\\n");
    String type = null;
    String serial = null;
    try {
        for(String s : arr) {                       
        if(s.isEmpty()) {
        textArea_1.append("Empty line" + '\n');
        s = getTextArea;
        }
    type = s.substring(0, 4);
    serial = s.substring(5, 12);
    URL url = new URL("blablabla" + type + serial);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    String result;
                    Scanner sc; 
                    sc = new Scanner(in);  
                    while(sc.hasNext()) {
                        result = sc.next();
                if (result.contains("Type:")) {
                            result = sc.nextLine();
                            result = sc.nextLine();
                            result = result.substring(26,30);
                            textArea_1.append(result + '\t');
                        }
                            result = sc.nextLine();
                            result = sc.nextLine();
                            result = result.substring(26, 29);
                            textArea_1.append(result + '\t');                               
                           }
                    }                       
                }   
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        } 
    });
```

Here is a picture to show the result
[image]

As you see after writing empty line the first line is repeated again !

Comment: where is the picture?

Comment: @SeekAddo
Just added

Comment: Your code example is inclomplete: you only add something to the `textArea_1` in the case of the empty line.

Comment: why do you keep adding getTextArea to the s. i think that is making it start over again

Comment: I think it should be if isEmpty it should write empty line and move on

Comment: ```s = getTextArea;``` does nothing, as ```s``` is discarded right after it.

Comment: @SeekAddo
I did add my full code almost

Comment: @SeekAddo
Yes I want it to write empty and then to continue, but this doesn't happen if I won't write [s = gettextArea;]

Comment: i think the s = gettextArea; should be outside the if block

Comment: @SeekAddo
if it will be outside it will keep repeat the same answer after empty line 3 times as below
3573
empty
3573
3573
3573

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of `s = getTextArea;` in the if block, you should have `continue;` to advance to the next element in `arr`.